# default parameters consuming a soap service on denodo

Tags: sql, soap, denodo

I have a question which I am trying to fix for some time but i can´t find the awnser to. I have a base view from a SOAP service in which im trying to make SQL querys. But the WSDL has a lot of optional parameters, if I don´t pass the optional parameters to the query it dosen´t work. Is there a way to skip value through the query or in the denodo configuration?

I am trying to consume a soap service as a database in denodo. I made a view but it asks for all parameters many of which i don´t have. Because of this i can´t query correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Virtual DataPort should mark the fields as optional if the web service has fields with the “minOccurs=0”. But when the web services use the “MaxOccurs/MinOccurs” in the WSDL, Virtual DataPort always creates the view with mandatory fields for every element although it uses the “minOccurs = 0”. The latest update includes a fix for this problem.

If you are a valid support user, you can download the latest update from the Denodo Support Site. You may refer to the Installing Updates and Hotfixes section of the Denodo Platform Installation Guide for more information.

Hope this helps!

This was the awnser from denodo team